# Computing the left annihilator $\text{Ann}_R(1_R-a)$ of a ring $R$.

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I was computing the left annihilators of the elements $x$ of a ring $R$ with $1_R$ (denoted by Ann$_R(x)$) and encountered the following scenario:

For any $a\in R$, $$\text{Ann}_R(1_R-a)=\{r\in R: r(1_R-a)=0\}=\{r\in R: r1_R-ra=0\}=\{r\in R: r=ra\}.$$
From this observation, I feel like concluding that $$\text{Ann}_R(1_R-a)=Ra.$$

My question is, should I conclude that that  $$\text{Ann}_R(1_R-a)=Ra?$$
Does it make sense?

Comment: You can certainly conclude that $\mathrm{Ann}_R(1_R-a)\subset Ra$, but the other inclusion does not necessarily hold. For example : any $a\neq1_R$ in a domain $R$.

Comment: Yes: the strategy of thinking of extremes is apropos here. In a domain, the only annihilator for a nozero element is $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, all you can conclude is that $r$ is a left-annihilator of $1-a$ if and only if $r=ra$.

That doesn't imply that for all $r\in R$, the element $ra$ is a left-annihilator of $1-a$.

For example, if $a\ne a^2$, the element $1a=a$ is not a left-annihilator of $1-a$.

Comment: Thank you! But I am not understanding the implication of $r\in \text{Ann}_R(1-a)$ iff $r=ra$, because I don't see how $r(1-a)=ra(1-a)=ra-ra^2$ goes to zero if $a\neq a^2$!

Comment: If $r$ is a left-annihilator of $1-a$, then $r(1-a)=0$, hence $r=ra$. Conversely, if $r=ra$, then $r(1-a)=0$, hence $r$ is a left-annihilator of $1-a$.

Comment: Thus, if $a\ne a^2$, then $a(1-a)\ne 0$, so $a$ is not a left-annihilator of $1-a$.

Comment: Exactly! my problem is the converse, you say if $r=ra$, then $r(1−a)=0$.  But all I see is that $r(1−a)=ra(1-a)=ra-ra^2\neq0$

Comment: $$r=ra\iff r-ra=0\iff r1-ra=0\iff r(1-a)=0$$